# mariadb cursor parameter marker issue

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mariadb

I am trying to execute a simple mariadb sql query using python and I am receiving the following error:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
>   that  corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
>   to use near '%s' at line 1

I am new to python and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I think the sql is valid, because I tried it and I also used this same syntax already before.

This is the code that isn't working:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect()

cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(operation="select max(parse_key) from nb.extracted_data where run_id = %s",params=(run_id))
```

I checked mysql docs and I think I am doing this correct:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

Please help me figure out what I have to do to correct the statement.

Comment: get rid of the params= and try it again please

Comment: That is how I had it originally. I got rid of both parameter names and it still doesn't work: cursor.execute("SELECT max(parse_key) FROM nb.extracted_data WHERE run_id=%s",(run_id))

Comment: Put a comma in between run_id and the closing parenthesis like this: `(run_id,)`. In Python, tuples with one element are funny that way. Alternatively (and I'm not certain it will work), use square brackets around the params instead.

Comment: That did it! I had even tried casting it to a tuple and that didn't work. Thanks for that @brentertainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like @brentertainer figured this out. The tuple needed a comma after run_id ie (run_id**,**).